Floor of a number in a sorted array with duplicates
Okay, so floor of a number in an array is defined as the largest number in the array that is lower than the provided number. If we find it in the array, we return its index, otherwise -1.
For example, arr = {1, 2, 4, 4, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12}.
Case 1, target = 4. Output is 1 (as arr[1] is the largest number smaller than target).
Case 2, target = 13. Output is 8 (as arr[8] is the largest number smaller than target).
Case 3, target = 0. Output is -1 (as there is no element greater than 0).
For an array that does not have any duplicates, it is just a binary search and returning high-1 and we get a time complexity of O(n).
But for an array that has duplicates, after performing binary search, the time complexity tends to O(n) as I have to linearly traverse back to get the the smallest element that is not equal to target itself.
For example, arr = {1, 2, 4, 4, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12}.
Case 1, target = 4.
Binary search gives me index 4 as arr[4] = 4. But I have to traverse back to get the largest number smaller than target.
Is there something that can help me remove the linear searching and just have log2(n) time complexity?

You need binary search with < rather than <=, that's all.

There are numerous versions of binary search. Please provide the code you have tried with.

After looking on the internet, I found the solution. I have also attached the video at the end.
The algorithm:

Declare a variable by the name lower_bound. This variable represents the smallest index for which arr[i] >= target and would be returned after the function executes.

Set lower_bound to arr.size. This is because if we have target that is greater than the largest element in arr, then lower_bound would be 1 greater than the maximum index as we want arr[lower_bound] >= target. For example, if target = 13, and arr[arr.size - 1] = 12. Hence arr.size would be returned.

Now we perform binary search. If arr[mid] >= target, we need to shorten our search space as we got a smaller index.

If arr[mid] < target, we set low = mid + 1.


Example:
If I take the above example only, arr = {1, 2, 4, 4, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12} and target = 4,
then the lower bound would be index 2, as 2 is the smallest index for which arr[i] >= target.

Initially, lower_bound = arr.size = 9.
We perform binary search, low = 0, high = arr.size - 1.
mid = 4, now arr[mid] also equals 4, therefore arr[mid] >= target, we set high = mid - 1 and lower_bound = 4.
mid = 2, again arr[mid] = 4, therefore, high = mid - 1 and lower_bound = 2.
mid = 1, now arr[mid] < target, therefore low = mid + 1.
Now low and high are at same index 2. We return lower_bound that also equals 2.

Upper bound can also be found the same way. Instead of arr[i] >= target, in case of upper bound it should be arr[i] > target.
Video Explanation I found on youtube
